# Fix datetime string in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, datetime, iso8601

I have a table with 43 000 000 rows. In datetime column data looks `2020.04.22T04:39:29.359` and it's of type `VARCHAR`.

It looks like an ISO format but there are `.`, and for ISO I need `-`.
What is the best way to convert the values in these rows to datetime?

One of my variant was subst . to -:

```
UPDATE table 
SET [Column 3] = REPLACE([Column 3], '.', '-');
```

but then I need to cut a microseconds from the end.

How to do this cut?

Or maybe you can advice more truish way.

Comment: *"and it's of type `VARCHAR`."* The *real* question is why are you using a `varchar` in the first place? Fix the design, fix the problem.

Comment: Be aware that `DATETIME`, unlike `DATETIME2`, does not support full precision in the milliseconds, it's only accurate (if you can call it that) to 3 milliseconds. A value like `04:39:29.359` in particular cannot be exactly represented and will be rounded to `04:39:29.360`. For some applications this doesn't matter, for others it does (when data has to be compared to the original). So while `VARCHAR` is definitely not the right type to use, `DATETIME` isn't necessarily either.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use `TRY_CONVERT` here, after first doing a bit of massaging to bring your raw datetime strings into a format which SQL Server recognizes:

```sql
UPDATE yourTable
SET new_dt_col = TRY_CONVERT(
                     datetime,
                     REPLACE(LEFT(dt_col, 19), '.', '-') + '.' + RIGHT(dt_col, 3)
                 );
```

To be explicit, the replacement logic used above would first convert this:

```
2020.04.22T04:39:29.359
```

into this:

```
2020-04-22T04:39:29.359
```

You may verify for yourself that the following conversion works correctly:

```sql
SELECT TRY_CONVERT(datetime, '2020-04-22T04:39:29.359');
```

Answer (score 1):

If every single row in the table has the date that follows the format **2020.04.22T04:39:29.359** you can do the following update statement:

```
UPDATE table 

SET [Column 3] = SUBSTRING([Column 3],1,4) + '-' + SUBSTRING([Column 3],6,2) + '-' + SUBSTRING([Column 3],9,15)
```

To only fix the 5th and 8th character without affecting the "." character from the microseconds.
After that you should be able to do the conversion to datetime.